# Selecting on a condition in window function postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql and applying window function. previously I had to find first gid with same last name , and address(street_address and city)   so i simply put last name in partition by clause in window function.

but now I have requirement to find first g_id of which last name is not same. while address is same How can I do it ?

This is what i was doing previously.

```
SELECT g_id as g_id,
 First_value(g_id) 
 OVER (PARTITION BY lname,street_address , city , 
           order by  last_date DESC NULLS LAST )as c_id,
street_address as street_address  FROM my table;
```

lets say this is my db

---

```
g_id | l_name | street_address | city | last_date
_________________________________________________
x1   | bar    | abc road       | khi  | 11-6-19

x2   | bar    | abc road       | khi  | 12-6-19

x3   | foo    | abc road       | khi  | 19-6-19

x4   | harry  | abc road       | khi  | 17-6-19

x5   | bar    | xyz road       | khi  | 11-6-19

_________________________________________________
```

In previous scenario : 
for  if i run for the first row my c_id, it should return  'x2' as it considers these rows:

```
_________________________________________________
g_id | l_name | street_address | city | last_date
_________________________________________________
x1   | bar    | abc road       | khi  | 11-6-19

x2   | bar    | abc road       | khi  | 12-6-19
_________________________________________________
```

and return a row with latest last_date.

what i want now to select these rows (rows with same street_address and city but no same l_name):

---

```
g_id | l_name | street_address | city | last_date
_________________________________________________
x1   | bar    | abc road       | khi  | 11-6-19

x3   | foo    | abc road       | khi  | 19-6-19

x4   | harry  | abc road       | khi  | 17-6-19
_________________________________________________
```

and output will be x3.

somehow i want to compare last_name column if it is not equals to the current value of last name and then partition by address field. and if no rows satisfy the condition c_id should be equal to current g_id

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output

Comment: How is `11-6-19` latest to `12-6-19`? Did you mean earliest?

Comment: please note I have used DESC while order by last_day , i want most row with the most recent date.

Comment: Is "raod" a typo? If you want to take another street name a more different name would be useful... I am still not sure what you mean with "where last name is not the same"... You sample is not very useful to stress this IMHO

Comment: yes raod is a typo let it just be any value. In window function , I want to select rows which do not have same l_name as the current value of iterator' last name  but same street_address and city.

Comment: typo fixed. @S-Man

Comment: In other words: You want to remove the l_name duplicates in each adress? For each adress each l_name should only occur one time? Why is x5 not in output?

Comment: i want to get the latest entry (which is determined by order by last_date desc), which have same street_address and city but different last_name than current. and fifth one is not in the answer as it has different street_address.

Comment: what is "current"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196565/discussion-between-aqeel-altaf-and-s-man).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how I solved it using subquery
creating example table.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
("g_id" varchar(2), "l_name" varchar(5), "street_address" varchar(8), "city" varchar(3), "last_date" date)
```

;

```
INSERT INTO mytable
("g_id", "l_name", "street_address", "city", "last_date")
VALUES
('x1', 'bar', 'abc road', 'khi', '11-6-19'),
('x2', 'bar', 'abc road', 'khi', '12-6-19'),
('x3', 'foo', 'abc road', 'khi', '19-6-19'),
('x4', 'harry', 'abc road', 'khi', '17-6-19'),
('x5', 'bar', 'xyz road', 'khi', '11-6-19')
```

;

query to get g_ids

```
SELECT * ,
(select b.g_id from mytable b where (base.g_id = b.g_id) or (base.l_name <> 
b.l_name and base.street_address = b.street_address and base.city = b.city ) 
order by b.last_date desc  limit 1)
from mytable base
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your expected output,it's not clear whether you want earliest or oldest for each group. You may change the `ORDER BY` accordingly for `last_date` in this query which uses `DISTINCT ON`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ( street_address, city, l_name) * 
   FROM   mytable 
ORDER  BY street_address, 
          city, 
          l_name, 
          last_date  --change this to last_date desc if you want latest
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d97b25edf508f6ab69a4f2e578e601e2)

Comment: how does this includes the part where I just want to consider rows which last_name is not equal to current row's last_name.

Comment: @AQEELALTAF : `l_name` is part of `DISTINCT ON`

Comment: Because under the first conditions the answer was quite correct, an upvote is necessary!

Comment: @S-Man : Thank you! We find very few questions in SO which have enough information beforehand, unless  seriously demanded.

Answer (score 1):

After discussing the details in this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196565/discussion-between-aqeel-altaf-and-s-man):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=db97575987ea7b7dd387655cb67c621b)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t1.g_id) 
    t1.*,
    COALESCE(t2.g_id, t1.g_id) AS g_id
FROM
    mytable t1
    LEFT JOIN mytable t2
    ON t1.street_address = t2.street_address AND t1.l_name != t2.l_name
ORDER BY t1.g_id, t2.last_date DESC
```